# Algorithm adapt RNG based on previous results

Tags: algorithm, random

I'm trying to reproduce some behavior for a simulator of mine.

I have a percentage check that can vary from 30% to 70%. The thing is it isn't strictly random. Here's the live data I extracted:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JLXRxh7xvR_fYwnTtvQ72jNV0v4lHiEEY6o-kG52wQA/pubhtml

Some things I noticed from the data:

- If the check fails once then the next check percentage is increased
- The 70% check never fails twice in a row.
- All first rounds seems to have a lower chance to succeed by 20%
- The server that generates the data uses PHP so it *may* be using the `rand()` function which is known to be pseudo-random

So I want to reproduce that behavior in Java. I could just code my own random class that follows those patterns but I'm not sure that my live data covers all cases so I was wondering: Would any existing PRNG algorithm comply with that behavior ? Also how would I ajust the chance so that the global ratio stays around the original value ?

Comment: Show us the code you got so far.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a couple flags. One to determine if it's the first check, and another to indicate if the previous check was a pass or a fail. Then set the percentage accordingly (50/70/100).

Comment: Clearly whatever you're checking is not a sequence of independent random variables, which is what random-number generators are designed to produce. Is there a limit on the number of consecutive successes? What makes the first time different?

Comment: Consider a check that looks at the last decimal digit of a certain integer variable. The check fails if the last decimal digit is 0, 1, or 2. You generate the first value of the integer variable uniformly in the range 0 to 5, inclusive. After each check, you add 7 to the variable, and the result is what you use for the next check. This has the properties you asked for but is obviously not random at all. _Is_ the phenomenon you're modeling actually random, and if so, how can you tell?

Comment: Perhaps what you're trying to model is a Markov process.

Comment: Another question: do you want 70% of _all_ checks to succeed in the long run, or only 70% of the checks that occur after a previous "success"?

Comment: @DavidK I added a link to a stylesheet containing some extracted data. It shows the global behavior i'm trying to reproduce. I'm not familiar with the Markov process so i'll read about it.

Comment: Basically, in a Markov process your system is in some state (e.g. "was hit" or "was not hit"). In each round you generate a new state. The probability of each state in any given round depends on previous state. Looking over your data, they seem to be remarkably consistent with a model in which you start in the "not hit" state, there is a 50% chance of a hit if the previous state was "not hit", and there is 0% chance of a hit if the previous state was "hit". In the long run this model produces 66.67% "not hit", on average, which is extremely close to what you observed.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that. FYI some people I asked about this told me about "non-resettability randomness" although they don't speak english that well and what I could find on google is "non-repeatability randomness". The thing is I then need to extend that for chances < 50% and i don't see how I could apply the same model to something > 70% and < 50% besides forcing the lowest probability result not to occur twice in a row.

Comment: I updated the stylesheet to have values from various percentages. It really never hits twice only with the 70% chance. Even 65% hit twice in a row once.

Answer (score 1):

This is so easy and so specific, that it is unlikely, someone already posted about this. It will be an honor to be the first.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class FailGenerator {
    private double firstChance;
    private double nextChance;
    private boolean first;
    private boolean lastResult;
    private Random r;

    public FailGenerator(){
        this(0.5, 0.7);
    }
    public FailGenerator(double firstChance, double nextChance){
        this.firstChance = firstChance;
        this.nextChance = nextChance;
        first = true;
        lastResult = true;
        r = new Random();
    }

    public boolean didHeSucceed(){
        if (lastResult == false){ //if he failed before
            lastResult = true;
        } else {
            double chance;
            if (first){
                first = false;
                chance = firstChance;
            } else {
                chance = nextChance;
            }

            if (r.nextDouble() <= chance){
                lastResult = true;
            } else {
                lastResult = false;
            }
        }

        return lastResult;
    }
}
```

Then if you call it as this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FailGenerator gen = new FailGenerator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        System.out.println("The result for iteration no. " + i + " is " + gen.didHeSucceed());
    }
}
```

The result would look like this :

```
The result for iteration no. 0 is false
The result for iteration no. 1 is true
The result for iteration no. 2 is false
The result for iteration no. 3 is true
The result for iteration no. 4 is true
The result for iteration no. 5 is true
The result for iteration no. 6 is true
The result for iteration no. 7 is true
The result for iteration no. 8 is true
The result for iteration no. 9 is false
The result for iteration no. 10 is true
The result for iteration no. 11 is true
The result for iteration no. 12 is true
The result for iteration no. 13 is true
The result for iteration no. 14 is true
The result for iteration no. 15 is false
The result for iteration no. 16 is true
The result for iteration no. 17 is true
The result for iteration no. 18 is false
The result for iteration no. 19 is true
The result for iteration no. 20 is true
The result for iteration no. 21 is false
The result for iteration no. 22 is true
The result for iteration no. 23 is false
The result for iteration no. 24 is true
The result for iteration no. 25 is true
The result for iteration no. 26 is true
The result for iteration no. 27 is true
The result for iteration no. 28 is false
The result for iteration no. 29 is true
The result for iteration no. 30 is true
The result for iteration no. 31 is true
The result for iteration no. 32 is false
The result for iteration no. 33 is true
The result for iteration no. 34 is true
The result for iteration no. 35 is false
The result for iteration no. 36 is true
The result for iteration no. 37 is true
The result for iteration no. 38 is true
The result for iteration no. 39 is true
The result for iteration no. 40 is true
The result for iteration no. 41 is true
The result for iteration no. 42 is false
The result for iteration no. 43 is true
The result for iteration no. 44 is true
The result for iteration no. 45 is false
The result for iteration no. 46 is true
The result for iteration no. 47 is true
The result for iteration no. 48 is false
The result for iteration no. 49 is true
```

Comment: `FailGenerator` as written above simulates a Markov process. After the first state, the transitions are false -> true (100%), true -> true (70%), false (30%). In the long run, because this process gives you "false" only after 30% of the "true" results and never after the "false" results, it is "true" 10/13 of the time, or about 76.9% of the time, not 70%. Maybe that's what OP wants; it's not clear.

Comment: That doesn't conform with what i'm looking for. What I need is something that will fix itself to tend to a global 70% rate even though on each hit there's a 100% chance it will miss afterwards.

Comment: @Crystark - it does, the only thing you have to change is what David K wrote you -> change the chance to 50%, then > `In the long run this model produces 66.67% "not hit", on average`. The only thing to make this work is change this line `this(0.5, 0.7);` to this `this(0.5, 0.5);`.

Comment: @libik Thanks. In your example though, shouldn't it be `r.nextDouble() < chance` due to the fact nextDouble can return 0 and that 0% chance should always fail ?